# Regarding code signing in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

I'm writting a framework for iOS and followed [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) tutorial to generate a fat binary with it. The framework is nearly at the point of deploy and I'm wondering how I should code sign it. My project is split in two parts, the framework, and the core. The core is written in C/C++ because it's shared with other platforms, and the framework is written in Objc. The core is a dependency of the first.

In the core I have the Team property set to None in the project's General configurations, and in the framework I have it set to my personal developer account.

My question is, how should I code sign the project, if at all, for distribution? Is a "personal" account (if there is such thing as a company accounts or something) enough? As the apps that will be using the framework will already be code signed, should I not do it?

Please enlighten.
Best.